# How to easily open a script in R-studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am very new to R-studio. In RGui, I was used to click `File / Open Script` to open a new script. But in R-studio, I only see `File / Open File` which generaly opens any file (?). The disadvantage is that I have many files in my directory and I want to see only `*.R` files when opening a script - which is what Rgui does and I love it - but cannot figure out how to do the same in R-studio.

Comment: RStudio supports a range of formats, and I don't think what you're after is possible. Sort the file browser pane by type?

Comment: @jbaums ok, but usualy such programs support more menu items for each type, like 'File / Open Script`, `File / Load Data` etc. This is not very friendly... thanks for the workaround though.

Comment: @jbaums, there is no "type" or "extension" column in the file pane! And I don't see any easy way how to add it.

Comment: There is a [website](https://support.rstudio.com) you can ask such kind of questions.

Comment: @TMS I disagree - your suggestion would require many additional File menu entries, since RStudio supports `.R`, `.Rmd`, `.cpp`, `.Rnw`, `.Rhtml`, `.Rpres`, `.Rd`, etc. etc.

Comment: (not sure what your OS is, but in Windows you need to change the view to Details to get the column headers including `Type`.)

Comment: @jbaums aha, you mean the OS' standard open dialog, I thought you mean the "Files" pane in R-studio... Thanks Pascal.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, you can just type

```
~>".R"
```

into the search box top right (while you are in your R folder), and you will only see files that end on .R

If you click into the search box, you see your past search queries, so you won't have to type it again every time you open a script.

If you use a different OS, look for a respective search "wildcard".

edit: "show file extensions" should be activated